# proguard errors with AndroidAsync

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have used [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) library in my android project.

Now compiling my project in release mode fails because of proguard warnings issued:

```
...
[proguard] Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.koushikdutta.async.wrapper.DataEmitterWrapper]
[proguard] Reading library jar [C:\old c Program Files\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar]
[proguard] Note: there were 474 duplicate class definitions.
[proguard] Initializing...
[proguard] Warning: com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getHostString()' in class java.net.InetSocketAddress
[proguard] Warning: com.koushikdutta.async.http.spdy.Spdy3$Writer: can't find referenced method 'int deflate(byte[],int,int,int)' in class java.util.zip.Deflater
[proguard] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[proguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[proguard]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[proguard]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[proguard]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
```

I added -libraryjars libs/androidasync-2.1.6.jar to proguard-project.txt but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently solved by adding the following line to proguard-project.txt:

```
-dontwarn com.koushikdutta.**
```